# java.util.HashSet.Contains testing leads to an inconsistent result

Tags: java, contains, hashset

I am currently using the java.util.HashSet to store some back references. In the test class I have the following piece of code :

```
    System.out.println("==========================================");
    for (Sequence<? extends Item> seq_i: m_sequences_references)
    {
        // Check hashCode
        System.out.println(seq_i.hashCode() == seq.hashCode());

        // Check reflexivity (o == e and e == o)
        System.out.println(seq_i.equals(seq));
        System.out.println(seq.equals(seq_i));

        // Check the default equal 
        System.out.println(seq == seq_i);
    }
    System.out.println(m_sequences_references.contains(seq));
    System.out.println("==========================================");
```

the achieved result is

```
==========================================
true
true
true
true
false
==========================================
```

I didn't override any method (hashCode, equals) and check that I didn't create by mistake an equals(AnythingButObject xx) method neither.

So my question is the following : I know that I have done something wrong but I don't know what to really check right now, do you have a suggestion ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that your object is mutable and `hashCode()` implementation depends on mutable fields. So first you've put the object into the set, then modified it changing its hashCode. However inside the `HashSet` the object  still persists in the old bucket which number is derived from the original hashCode, thus it cannot be found.

As a general rule: never modify objects in `HashSet` or objects used as `HashMap` keys.